# how do I keep track of player's turn in game?

Tags: javascript

I have created a game that will display the winner with the highest score on the screen. There are two buttons for players one and two. Users will play game to a set score. For example, if the game is set to 5, the user will click both buttons until button one or button two reach the winning score of 5. The header may display "congratulations Player 1 win score of 5 to 4". Players should not be able to keep clicking one button to reach the winning score of 5. However, how do I keep track of player's turn in game?  Below is the code:

```
score.html file:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>score</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="score.css">
</head>
<body>
 <h1> <span id="p1Display" > <span id="player1Win"></span> 0</span> to <span id="p2Display">0</span></h1> 

 <p>Play to: <span>5</span> </p>

 <input type="number">
 <button id="p1">Player one</button>
 <button id="p2">Player two</button>
 <button id="reset">Reset</button>


    <script src="score.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
score.js file:

p1Button.addEventListener("click", function () {
    if (!gameOver) {
        if(turnTacker == 0) {
            turnTacker = 1;
            p1Score++;
        }else {
            turnTacker = 0;
            p2Score++;
        }

        if (p1Score === winningscore) {
            p1Display.classList.add("winner");
            gameOver = true; //stop adding to score
        }
        p1Display.textContent = p1Score;

        if (gameOver ) {
            p1Display.textContent = `congratulations Player 1 win score of ${p1Score}`; 
        }


    }
});

p2Button.addEventListener("click", function () {
   if (!gameOver) {
        if(turnTacker == 0) {
            turnTacker = 1;
            p2Score++;
        }else {
            turnTacker = 0;
            p1Score++;
        }

        if (p2Score === winningscore) {
            p2Display.classList.add("winner");
            gameOver = true; //stop adding to score
        }
        p2Display.textContent = p2Score;

        if (gameOver ) {
            p2Display.textContent = `congratulations Player 2 win score of ${p2Score}`; 
        }


    }
});


resetButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
    reset(); //function to start over
    p1Score = 0; //set player score back to 0
    p2Score = 0;
    //update score on html page to 0
    p1Display.textContent = 0;
    p2Display.textContent = 0;
    //remove winner class from both p1 &p2
    p1Display.classList.remove("winner");
    p2Display.classList.remove("winner");
    gameOver = false;

});


//start game over/reset to 0
function reset() {
    p1Score = 0; //set player score back to 0
    p2Score = 0;
    //update score on html page to 0
    p1Display.textContent = 0;
    p2Display.textContent = 0;
    //remove winner class from both p1 &p2
    p1Display.classList.remove("winner");
    p2Display.classList.remove("winner");
    gameOver = false;
}


numInput.addEventListener("change", function () {
   // winningscoreDisplay.textContent = numInput.value; //update winng score get value from text field
    winningscoreDisplay.textContent = this.value; //update winng score get value from text field
    winningscore = Number(this.value); //get and set value in textfield. Turn into number
    //winningscore = Number(numInput.value); //get and set value in textfield. Turn into number
    reset();//once input number run reset
});
```

Comment: I have updated the code but I can't get the game to keep track of who turn it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For two players you will need a toggle. This can be a value from a hidden field in the page DOM, or just a `JS` variable as long as the page is not refreshed. Or to take it a step further you can keep track of turns on a server, yet this sounds too advanced for now.

A toggle can be based on an even/odd calculation, or just an if statement. something like:

```
    if(turn==0){turn=1}else{turn=0}
```

the above line is like an `on/off` switch, is the turn `off`, player1 can play, and his/her action will turn it `on`. When the switch is `on` player2 can play and his/her action will turn it `off` again.

or if you have more than two players

```
    turn++; // before turn increase by 1 each time

    // do everything here for the current player

    if(turn >= countPlayers()){turn=0} // reset to 0 after the last player
```

in this concept there is no value 0 as we start at 1 with the ++ before the first turn, then increase the turn each time a player did something until the total count of players have played and then reset back to 0.

The even/odd calculation is a simple alternative for a toggle if you have just two players. Since you are already keeping track of the total rounds played, there is no need for an extra variable.

```
    function checkOdd(int){
      return int % 2;
    }

    if(checkOdd(turnTacker)){
      // player2 has to play
    }else{
      // player1 has to play
    };
```

If `turnTacker` is `0` checkOdd is `FALSE`, if `turnTacker` is `1` checkOdd is `TRUE`, if `turnTacker` is `2` checkOdd is `FALSE`, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is add another variable which says whose turn it is.
For example:

```
var p1turn = true;
while (i < //a certain number of turns) {
   if (p1turn) {
      //something player 1 does
      p1turn = false;
      i++;
   }
   else {
      //something player 2 does
      p1turn = true;
      i++;
   }
}
```

Hope this helps!